# Is the genesis built on the MAC different from the genesis built on Linux

Tags: wasm, genesis

If you register `parathread` with genesis and WASM generated on the MAC, then run the blockchain on Linux. Will this future run blockchain and fail?

Answer (score 4):

If you create a genesis on Mac and on Linux, they may differ, and that is OKAY.

There will be no issues running a genesis generated on Mac with a node running on Linux.

The genesis of a chain is entirely operating system agnostic. It is either a JSON object with non-encoded values, or a RAW spec is just directly encoded key and value pairs.

The difference here will be with the Wasm included in the genesis, which will work on both operating systems, since Wasm is a platform agnostic format, but there may be artifacts in the Wasm which are specific to an OS, or even specific to the time or way to compile the Wasm.

End of the day, these artifacts to not impact the final code which is executed, my understanding is these are mostly metadata stuff which can ultimately cause differences in the final generated object.